# Diamond-shaped relationships - identifying or non-identifying?

Tags: database-design, foreign-keys, relational-database, relationship, foreign-key-relationship

My question is related to this one: [How to keep foreign key relations consistent in a "diamond-shaped" system of relationships](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12288579/how-to-keep-foreign-key-relations-consistent-in-a-diamond-shaped-system-of-rel)

I have a very similar problem: A **venue** contains many **seats**. A **venue** also hosts many **events**. I need to keep track of which seats are booked in each event. This information is kept in the **event_seat** table, which has identifying relationships with both **event** and **seat** (i.e. its primary key identifies both an event and a seat).

[image: One non-identifying relationship]

I want to enforce the restriction that each row in **event_seat** must refer to an **event** and to a **seat** that belong to the same **venue**. I considered converting **event -> venue** into an identifying relationship by making `venue_id` part of the primary key for `event`, like so:

[image: Only identifying relationships]

Doing so would allow me to define two foreign keys for `event_seat` as follows:

```
(venue_id, event_id) references event(venue_id, event_id)
(venue_id, seat_id) references seat(venue_id, seat_id)
```

This definition would guarantee the desired restriction (the event must take place in the same venue to which the seat belongs). However, `venue_id` is actually a function of `event_id`, so `(venue_id, event_id)` is not a minimal superkey. Doesn't this violate some fundamental principle about primary keys? What other options do I have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `seat_id` is not unique by itself and is not functionally dependent on `venue_id` (nor vice-verse). That's why you should probably name it something like `seat_no`. Ditto for `event_id`.

If you want a "simple" field that is unique by itself, you can always introduce a [surrogate key](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/surrogate-key/info) *in addition* to the composite key produced by the identifying relationships.

---

Alternatively, you can make the `seat_id` alone a key, but introduce a *redundant* UNIQUE constraint covering `{venue_id, seat_id}`, solely for the purpose of being referenced by the "bottom" of the diamond.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer!
You are right about `seat_id`. I should probably rename it.
You are wrong about `event_id`, though: `event_id` _is_ unique by itself and should be enough to identify the event. If `venue_id` was independent of `event_id`, I wouldn't have any problem with the bottom diagram. The problem I have is with the relationship between `event` and `venue`, not between `seat` and `venue`.

Comment: @RonInbar I doesn't _have_ to be unique, based on your model alone. If there is some other business rule I'm not aware of forcing it to be unique, then just make it a surrogate key and use a separate field (e.g. `event_no`) for the purpose of correctly modelling the diamond-shaped dependency. Or use the alternative solution (redundant UNIQUE).