# Database design issue: History consistency

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database, rdbms

I don't know what is the term it used to define this problem, let me explain here with a simple example. I have a `products` and `orders` table, with `orders` having one to many relationship with `ordered_products` table.

See the tables:-

```
products(id, sku, name, summary, price);

orders(id, code, customer_name, customer_address);
ordered_products(id, order_id, product_id, quantity);
```

Once the orders are generated, the ordered products are listed in the `ordered_products` table. The application then generates an invoice at that instance taking the price reference from the `products` table. Problem occurs! when the product that has been ordered get edited. For example if name or price is edited on the `products` table, the orders is affected creating a mismatch in actual orders. What's the solution here? Do I need to copy the values in the `ordered_items` rather than using a foreign key reference here?

Comment: You may want to take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11930467/533120

Answer (score 1):

An order is 'normally' placed at an agreed price, so changing of the product price after the order is placed does mean that you have to store the ordered_price in the ordere_products table.